# How to find if a string is equal to another from a list in C++

Tags: c++, string, translators

I'm making a Latin translator and I need some help. So the way I've done this is I've separated each word from a phrase the user inputs into separate strings. I also have a class where i just list all of the Latin words and its translation
for example:
    `string ac = "and";` and
    `string accedo = "approach";`

I want a way to check for example the first word to all the words from the list to find what the translation is, without adding an if statement for every word.

Comment: Lookup `std::map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) like this

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> words;

    words["ac"] = "and";
    words["acedo"] = "approach";


    std::cout << "ac = " << words["ac"] << '\n';
    std::cout << "acedo = " << words["acedo"] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks I'll try it out!

Comment: after I've done this how would I use it to cross check it to the strings in the other class?

Comment: after doing this all the words got a integral constant expression error. No idea how to fix this, is this because it wasn't put inside of the main class?

Comment: @SpencerHopkins I don't know what you are doing exactly so I can't see what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: i put it in the main class and it's working fine but how would i check to see which of the words in the map are equal to my string

Comment: @SpencerHopkins If your `string` is called `my_word` you simply do `std::string translation = words[my_word];`

Comment: THANKS MAN! you've been a big help to a novice such as myself. Only been doing C++ for like 4-5 months.